# Key metrics in CUDA code optimization

Tags: cuda

I have the following metrics for my code:

```
Warp Execution Efficiency      74.65%

Achieved Occupancy             0.356603
```

If I change a few things I am receiving:

```
Warp Execution Efficiency      89.51%

Achieved Occupancy             0.246908
```

I must notice, though, I haven't any benefit in execution time.

I just want to know what is more vital metrics to look up? The warp execution maybe since the occupancy doesn't say much to performance?

Comment: `Achieved occupancy` usually depends on your program overall configuration over the GPU Streaming Multiprocessor resources. Asking for too much shared memory or registers in a block, for example, causes SM not to be able to have the maximum number of threads it can support queued in scheduler. On the other hand, `warp execution efficiency` depends on your program control flow. Having too many conditional statements in your code that make warp lanes diverge reduces execution efficiency.

Comment: There's no definite answer to your question. It really depends on what your code does, and what your CUDA device characteristics are.

Comment: I think that, in CUDA optimization, the only "vital" parameter to look at is the execution time `t`. I would say that the optimization problem can be formalized as the optimization of the functional `t=t(m1,m2,...)`. The parameters `mi` are the performance metrics, as for example, occupancy, warp efficiency, cache misses, etc. The performance metrics are the "observables" of the problem and are functions of the algorithm structure and of the algorithm parameters, as for example the `BLOCK_SIZE`. In principle, you should find the algorithm structure and parameters minimizing `t`.

Comment: Again in principle, you should find the global minimum of `t=t(m1,m2,...)` by using some numerical optimization algorithm, but this would be quite impossible. Fortunately, you have some information on the behavior of `t` against individual parameters. For example, you know that, under some conditions, `t` is a decreasing function of the warp efficiency, which would lead to choose the algorithm structure and parameters to improve that metrics.

Comment: @JackOLantern:Ok, thank you.I think you should make it an answer.

Comment: The two metrics are orthogonal. Ideally you would be able to increase both average active threads per warp and number of eligible warps. With an occupancy of 25% you are definitely starving the schedulers. I agree with JackOLantern that the most critical item is execution time. All other metrics are just clues on how to possibly modify your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, in CUDA optimization, the only "vital" parameter to look at is the execution time `t`. I would say that the optimization problem can be formalized as the optimization of the functional

```
t=t(m1,m2,...).
```

The parameters `mi` are the performance metrics, as for example, occupancy, warp efficiency, cache misses, etc. The performance metrics are the "observables" of the problem and are functions of the algorithm structure and of the algorithm parameters, as for example the `BLOCK_SIZE`. In principle, you should find the algorithm structure and parameters minimizing `t`.

Again in principle, you should find the global minimum of `t=t(m1,m2,...)` by using some numerical optimization algorithm, but this would be quite impossible in practice. Fortunately, you have some information on the behavior of `t` against individual parameters. For example, you know that, under some conditions, `t` is a decreasing function of the warp efficiency, which would lead to choose the algorithm structure and parameters to improve that metrics.